# Ignoring 'Unknown property value' in Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome's dev tools become almost unusable if you use a lot of vendor prefixes and have long property values...

[image: http://c.littke.com/image/2v3V2Q051W3i]

Is there a way to tell the dev tools not to display the 'Unknown property values' (e.g the ones with a triangle)?

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to fully hide all unrecognized style properties, because that would make it too easy to accidentally overlook a mistake.

<strike>You can customize the developer tools via a custom User style (it's not an extension).</strike>

First locate your profile directory, then enter the `User StyleSheets` subdirectory. You'll find a file called `Custom.css`. Edit this file, and add the following:

EDIT: Custom user styles have been removed from Chromium. To change the appearance of the developer tools, the new `chrome.devtools.panels.applyStyleSheet` method can be used ([sample code](https://github.com/paulirish/sample-devtools-theme-extension)).

```
#-webkit-web-inspector .properties > .not-parsed-ok:not(.child-editing):not(:hover) {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

This CSS selector selects all CSS property-value pairs which are invalid, and force all content on single line, unless you're editing it, or hovering your mouse on it. If you *really* want to hide styles, use `display:none;`.
For the reasons given above, I would use something else, such as `max-height: 8px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` instead of `display:none;` to hide the properties. Then, you can still see that incorrect properties exist, without being bothered too much.

An alternative style is to indeed hide all properties by default, and only show the hidden properties when the mouse is on the CSS declaration:

```
#-webkit-web-inspector .properties:not(:hover) > .not-parsed-ok:not(.child-editing) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice answer! Will investigate and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding these unconditionally puts you on a slippery road. Consider yourself adding a property and **inadvertently dropping a single character** in the property name (`background-colr`) or value (`rb(128,120,120)`) (*these typos are there for a reason, do not edit!*). This property will instantly disappear, and you will have no way to restore it (by editing the CSS model), yet this broken property will remain in the style sheet text forever. That's why we don't hide them.

Comment: Indeed! But making them smaller or on just one line as Rob W suggests sounds like a nice way forward. Especially when using a framework like Bootstrap which automatically generates vendor-prefixed versions of box-shadow, border-radius and every other mixin I use. In these cases it'd be nice to have an option to always ignore -moz, etc, basically all overridden vendor-prefix'ed properties! :)

Comment: Here's another example of where almost half the rules are struck out: http://c.littke.com/image/3Q3c342W1o1s

Comment: It's not the strike-out that should concern one, but the warning marks next to the properties... Still, I agree it might be a good idea to optionally hide vendor-prefixed properties. Mind filing a bug at http://crbug.com/new against Developer Tools?

Comment: My brain has already ignored those, since I'm so used to seeing them. I'll file a bug.

Comment: Didn't see where to file it against 'Developer Tools' specifically. Here it is though, if you want to change: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242499&thanks=242499&ts=1369141238

Comment: @JonatanLittke: thanks! (I forgot to mention that you can file a bug by going to chrome://chrome/ and clicking the `Report an issue` button, which will bring you to a wizard where you can choose "Developer tools" as the issue component).

Comment: OK awesome. If I have a not related (yet simple) feature request for developer tools, are you interested and if so, where can I send it? Was looking for your contact info but can't find it on the web. I'm @jonatanlittke if you want to find my email. Cheers.

Comment: @JonatanLittke: we accept feature requests on par with bug reports at http://crbug.com. I've mixed things up, actually: to start the issue filing wizard, you need to click the `New issue` button in the top left corner (and at the second step, choose "Developer Tools"). We also have a support mailgroup, https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30383/discussion-between-jonatan-littke-and-alexander-pavlov)